# Can we really use "Same here" in this context?

Tags: grammar, logic

> Why do you sing?
>
> Because I love it. I want everyone to hear my singing.
>
> Same here.
>
> Huh?
>
> I am a cop, because I want to save people.
>   Isn't that enough of a reason? It doesn't matter if someone
>   acknowledge me or not.

Isn't there a logic gap here? He says "Same here", but "I want to hear everyone to hear my singing" implies she wants to be acknowledged.

Comment: Maybe the cop's answer concerns the statements "Because I love it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does a cop do? Help prevent crime? How? Of course but investigating the case and catching the culprit. But, in addition, cops also play a vital role in spreading awareness amongst people. The awareness of being a responsible citizen, and also obey laws.

Well, that's what the cop is trying to tell the other person.

> Why do you sing ~ Because I love it. ***I want everyone to hear*** my singing

The 'same here' means the cop wants everyone to listen to him to prevent crime and also to save people from being a victim.

Comment: So when you say "Same here" your following statement doesn't have to perfectly match everything a character said?

Comment: Depends on the context. Compare this - I always prefer going to a Chinese restaurant and order noodles ~ same here... But I order manchurian. It's the same but not same...